# How to initialize UIColor from RGB values properly?

Tags: uibutton, rgb, uicolor

I am working on an iPhone application which uses various colors. When user selects the particular color button I set drawing color accordingly. I am getting the color for some but in the most of the cases I am getting white color.

Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)colorSelected:(UIButton *)sender
{

switch (sender.tag) 
{
    case 1:
        self.drawcolor= [UIColor colorWithRed:200 green:191 blue:231 alpha:1];
        break;            
    case 2:
        self.drawcolor= [UIColor colorWithRed:163 green:73 blue:164 alpha:1];
        break;  
    case 3:
        self.drawcolor= [UIColor colorWithRed:112 green:146 blue:76 alpha:1];
        break;  
    case 4:
        self.drawcolor= [UIColor colorWithRed:63 green:72 blue:204 alpha:1];
        break;  
    case 5:
        self.drawcolor= [UIColor colorWithRed:153 green:217 blue:234 alpha:1];
        break;  
    case 6:
        self.drawcolor= [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:162 blue:232 alpha:1];
        break;          
    case 7:
        self.drawcolor= [UIColor colorWithRed:181 green:230 blue:29 alpha:1];
        break;  
    case 8:
        self.drawcolor= [UIColor colorWithRed:34 green:177 blue:76 alpha:1];
        break;          
    case 9:
        self.drawcolor= [UIColor colorWithRed:239 green:228 blue:176 alpha:1];
        break;          
    case 10:
        self.drawcolor= [UIColor colorWithRed:255 green:201 blue:0 alpha:1];
        break;          
    case 11:
        self.drawcolor= [UIColor colorWithRed:255 green:201 blue:14 alpha:1];
        break;          
    case 12:
        self.drawcolor= [UIColor colorWithRed:237 green:28 blue:36 alpha:1];
        break;          
    case 13:
        self.drawcolor= [UIColor colorWithRed:255 green:127 blue:39 alpha:1];
        break;          
    case 14:
        self.drawcolor= [UIColor colorWithRed:255 green:174 blue:201 alpha:1];
        break;          
    case 15:
        self.drawcolor= [UIColor colorWithRed:185 green:122 blue:87 alpha:1];
        break;          
    case 16:
        self.drawcolor= [UIColor colorWithRed:136 green:0 blue:21 alpha:1];
        break;          
    case 17:
        self.drawcolor= [UIColor colorWithRed:195 green:195 blue:195 alpha:1];
        break;          
    case 18:
        self.drawcolor= [UIColor colorWithRed:127 green:127 blue:127 alpha:1];
        break;          
    case 19:
        self.drawcolor= [UIColor colorWithRed:255 green:255 blue:255 alpha:1];
        break;
    case 20:
        self.drawcolor= [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
        break;  
    default:
        break;
}

self.preColor=self.drawcolor;
self.lineWidth=self.prelineWidth;
}
```

Can any one tell me what I am doing wrong ?
Sumit

Comment: I stumbled upon a nice utility http://colorcode.globalmaverick.com/ it gives u Objecive-c and swift usable code directly from HEX color code or RGB.

Answer (score 200, accepted):

The values are in the `0.0` to `1.0` range.

E.g. divide by `255.`, but remember the decimal dot so you get floating point division and not integer division.

Like

```
selectedColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:14.0/255.0 green:114.0/255.0 blue:199.0/255.0 alpha:1];
```

Comment: To expand on Mats answer, here it is with an example: self.drawcolor =[UIColor colorWithRed:14.0/255.0 green:114.0/255.0 blue:199.0/255.0 alpha:1];

Answer (score 14):

Pragmatic approach with **Swift**.

```
extension UIColor {

   convenience init(rgbColorCodeRed red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int, alpha: CGFloat) {

     let redPart: CGFloat = CGFloat(red) / 255
     let greenPart: CGFloat = CGFloat(green) / 255
     let bluePart: CGFloat = CGFloat(blue) / 255

     self.init(red: redPart, green: greenPart, blue: bluePart, alpha: alpha)

   }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You got several options

**Code**

```
CGFloat red = 16.0;
CGFloat green = 97.0;
CGFloat blue = 5.0;
CGFloat alpha = 255.0;
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:(red/255.0) green:(green/255.0) blue:(blue/255.0) alpha:(alpha/255.0)];
```

**Color picker plugin for Interface Builder**

There's a nice color picker from Panic which works well with IB: http://panic.com/~wade/picker/

**Xcode plugin**

This one gives you a GUI for choosing colors: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eblRfDQM0Go

**Pods and libraries**

There's a nice pod named `MPColorTools`: https://github.com/marzapower/MPColorTools

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that you can easily turn into a category on UIColor that will allow you to specify a color based on RGBA values of 0 - 255.

```
+ (UIColor *)colorFromRGBAWithRed:(CGFloat)red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue alpha:(CGFloat)alpha {
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:red/255.0 green:green/255.0 blue:blue/255.0 alpha:alpha/255.0];
}
```

If you make it a UIColor category extension, you can use it like so:

```
UIColor *myAwesomeColor = [UIColor colorFromRGBAWithRed:48 green:119 blue:167 alpha:255];
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift you can easily set your Background-Color for example of a cell like this:

`cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 14.0/255.0, green: 114.0/255.0, blue: 199.0/255.0, alpha: 1)`

:-)

Answer (score 0):

```
(ContentView.Layer.BorderColor) //CG Object
   = UIColor.LightGray.CGColor;
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".