# In Xcode 6 Beta 4 stroking with SKShapeNode doesn't work anymore

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, xcode6

In Xcode 6 beta 2 it worked fine, but in beta 4 it doesn't work anymore. Does anyone know what's behind this mystery?

```
let circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 125);
circle.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 1.0);
circle.lineWidth = 4
self.addChild(circle);
```

In beta 4 nothing can be seen.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to initialize UIColor from RGB values properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023916/how-to-initialize-uicolor-from-rgb-values-properly) and many other similar questions: The red/green/blue parameters are floating point numbers **in the range 0.0 .. 1.0**.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I give it it try.

Comment: @MartinR - despite the mistake in using 255 instead of 1.0, he seems to be right - it doesn't work (using 255 would default to 1.0 anyway) - the circle is filled (if you add that in), but not stroked, even if you make all of the parameters CGFloats in the correct range...

Comment: @Grimxn: OK, I have retracted my closing vote.

Comment: Maybe you are misunderstanding stroke? It's not a fill pattern but the outline of the path. Try setting both fill and stroke color.

Comment: I tried it with the correct color format but still no luck with the stroke.
It fills the circle, but no outline at all and that is what I need.

I used both the fill and stroke too:

   circle.fillColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 0.5);

        circle.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0);

Comment: iOS 8 beta 3 and 4 have Sprite Kit issues. The Apple Developer forums have some additional information on it.

Comment: I have similar problems with SKShapeNodes in Xcode 6 beta 4. Color-transparency issues + stroke (color/lineWidth/glowWidth) issues, etc.

Comment: I guess the same problem exists also in Xcode 6 beta 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common issue with Xcode 6 Beta 4 when using the simulator. **It renders fine when using an actual device**. [See this developer forums thread](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1008647#1008647). It is worth noting that the issue is exclusive to stroking in that setting `circle.fillColor` still fills the circle (or whatever your `SKShapeNode` is drawing) correctly.

Also keep in mind that when [initializing a `UIColor` with RGB values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023916/how-to-initialize-uicolor-from-rgb-values-properly) the RGB values must be between (inclusive) 0.0 and 1.0.

```
circle.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0);
```

Or alternatively use the preset:

```
circle.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Comment: Seems to also be an issue with XCode 6.0.1, too.