# Draw rectangle in spritekit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm trying to draw an empty rectangle with a SKShapeNode but does appear on the screen. If i set a color to the fill property the rectangle appears. What could be the issue?

//MyScene.h

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
@interface MyScene : SKScene
@end
```

//MyScene.m

```
#import "MyScene.h"

@implementation MyScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

        SKShapeNode *shapeNode = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithRectOfSize:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2)];
        shapeNode.strokeColor = [SKColor redColor];
        shapeNode.lineWidth = 3;

       [self addChild:shapeNode];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Did you try increasing line width?

Comment: EDITED: It works for me on a device. Not on the simulator.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24951185/in-xcode-6-beta-4-stroking-with-skshapenode-doesnt-work-anymore

Comment: Used the following line:
`shapeNode.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor();`
Got the follwing error:
Called object type 'UIColor *' is not a function or function pointer

Used the following line:
`shapeNode.strokeColor = [UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)];`
Got the follwing error:
Expected Identifier