# Set custom background color on a stack in Swift (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui, background-color

My code currently consists of:

```
VStack{
   Text("Something")
}
.background(Color.red)
```

I want to use a custom color for the background instead of Color.red. However, looking at the documentation, it seems like the background function takes in a background. Therefore, I can't declare a variable:

```
let exampleColor : Color = Color(red: 141, green: 223, blue: 144)
```

and use it within the background function. How do I tackle this problem?

```
VStack{
   Text("Something")
}
.background(exampleColor)
```

Doesn't work.

Comment: I think you have to pass value between  0 to 1 for RGB Color like change `Color(red: 141, green: 223, blue: 144)` to `Color(red: 141/255, green: 223/255, blue: 144/255)` or use `Color(red: 1, green: 0.8, blue: 0)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to initialize UIColor from RGB values properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023916/how-to-initialize-uicolor-from-rgb-values-properly)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set values between 0 to 1 for `RGB Colors`. Use the following

```
let exampleColor : Color = Color(red: 141/255, green: 223/255, blue: 144/255)
```

or value between 0 to 1 like

```
let exampleColor : Color = Color(red: 0.5, green: 0.8, blue: 0.5)
```